# Fetched later/deferred and gotten now

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I have two questions.

- Is there a noun for something which should be deferred?
- What would be the opposite for something which should be "fetched later"?

Comment: What do you mean by "deferred" and "fetch later"? Could you please give some examples?

Comment: You defer something if you do not do it right now but later.

Comment: Does it have to be an noun? If its a class name, would an adjective suffice?  "Deferred" or "Postponed" sound like class names to me.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence showing how you would use the words you're looking for?

Comment: Have you perhaps mistyped something in your second question? Surely the opposite of *"something which should be deferred"* isn't *"something which should be fetched later"* - it's *"something which should be fetched **immediately**"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly an everyday word, but [deferrable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deferrable) *- [item] capable of or suitable or eligible for being deferred* is listed as a noun by Merriam-Webster.

[Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deferrables%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are some instances in print from Google Books (and some [deferables](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deferables%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)), where OP might be gratified to see that the antonym *non-deferrables* is also used.

The fact that it's not common isn't an issue - the meaning should be obvious on first encounter. Contexts vary, but often a *deferable* (my preferred spelling) means a "major purchase" (car, house, etc.) that can be delayed if money is tight - as opposed to *non-deferables* (food, toilet paper, etc.).

Comment: I think we have a winner here.  Still, I’d have thought that that would have been spelled *referrible*, as in *inferrible*. The [online OED3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/160864) does indeed attest *referrible* as an adjective, but says it’s now “rare” for the *deferable* spelling. The latest citation given is from 1945: “It is not possible to carry out the proof without using proofs ***referrible*** to a particular domain of knowledge.” That sounds, and looks, perfectly fine to me. Regarding *ible*-vs-*able*, they also have an 1873 citation for *intransferrible* instead of *intransferable*.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know where you find justification for *inferrible*. Per [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inferrible%2Cinferible%2Cinferrable%2Cinferable&year_start=1900&year_end=2005&corpus=0&smoothing=3), both *inferrable* (and the more normal *inferable*) are streets ahead of either version with an "i" (which I have to say both look terrable to me! :)

Comment: I think you may be making a false inferance there.

Comment: @tchrist: haha. Seriously though, I can see that double-r *inferrible* at nearly 16K hits outranks the single-r version at only 1K. And it is odd that with "a", the double-r version (29K hits) is swamped by single-r (244K). But why would you expect the "i" versions today anyway? They virtually disappeared over a century ago.

Comment: I would expect that *‑ent*, *‑ence*, and *‑ible* words derived from the same root tend to go together, just as *‑ant*, *‑ance*, and *‑able* words similarly derived also tend to go together. I would expect a double-r because it is *inferred*, *referred*, and *deferred*. And I couldn’t give a rat’s patute about a sloppy popularity contest overruling common sense and historical accuracy. There is often a hidden method to the apparent 
madness of English spelling, and those who muck with it out of ignorance do violence to those few strands of reason holding little pieces of it together.

Comment: EN, NF *terrible* < LA *terribilis* < LA *terrēre*. EN *referrible* < LA *referibilis* < LA *referre*. If you must know, the Latin verbs of **other** than the 1st conjugation are those that gave us the *‑e‑/‑i‑* forms (and the Romance tongues plenty of *‑ir* verbs, and sometimes *-er*), whereas the Latin 1st conjugation verbs (which gave rise to *‑ar* verbs in most modern Romance apart from French), Germanic roots, and the native English productive inflection give rise to the *‑a‑* forms. It isn’t without exception, but it’s more often right than wrong, and actually explains why this all is.

Comment: I must admit I don't much like those double-r's. My natural inclination is to write, say, *non-transferable*. Which I will do unless I'm in a context where some spell-checker picks me up on it. But you'll have a hard time convincing the rest of the world that words ending in *-fer* should all be extended with *-ible* rather than *-[r]able*.

Comment: I bet you’re the guy responsible for giving us the disgustingly deranged `HTTP_REFERER` instead of the correct spelling in the eponymous protocol. Rimnods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4136/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-tchrist)

Answer (score 4):

I would just refer to something that has been deferred as "the deferred".

"Defer" can be used on a wide range of things e.g. Decisions, tasks, chores, events, and so, the common practice would be to add "defer" before the thing:

> Deferred task
>   Deferred decision

etc.

Comment: I do not need to describe anything specific which is deferred. Instead I am looking for a word for anything deferred.

Answer (score 4):

What about *[shelved](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shelve)*?

> : to put off or aside  [*shelve* a project]

From another [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shelve):

> : to put aside or postpone from consideration

Comment: It seems to me that the meaning is a bit like sorted.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.

Comment: As an example for shelved the sentence "The books were shelved according to category." is given. Isn't this some kind of sorting?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a single word for either of these concepts.  Possibly *"restoree"* might fit for something which had been deferred but has now been fetched, but that's not quite what you are asking for.

I would normally call something which should be deferred "something which should be deferred".  Beyond that, I would have to start artificially constructing words like "deferand", which I don't think would help.

Comment: SomethingWhichShouldBeDeferred is a bit long as a class name ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions:

1. **back burner** = reduced priority; put aside for the time being, as a subject that is not of immediate concern but that may be activated later; postponed

Although this word is often used inside the phrase "[on the back burner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/back+burner)," it also has a [Verb form](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back%20burner) and would be enough to suit your need for a "class name"

1. **ancillary** = the meaning of "ancillary" as an Adjective is precise: "[of secondary importance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ancillary)."

As a Noun, it means a subsidiary or auxiliary thing.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of college admissions, a student who should be deferred would be *waitlisted*.

I know of no inverse of waitlisted.

Comment: "Expedited" as an antinym to "waitlisted".

Comment: OP would be looking for the inverse of "waitlisted." Would a student who was waitlisted be placed in an "expedited" category? If this were a Finite State Automaton, I think a student's application could go from (1) applied to (2) waitlisted to (9) accepted. Or from (1) applied to (3) expedited to (9) accepted. But probably not (1) applied to (2) waitlisted to (3) expedited to (9) accepted.

Comment: I saw nothing from the Op with regard to progression - merely antonyms and synonyms. To me, if a student is waitlisted, he is put in a pending list (like standby for air tickets, perhaps). However, if the student is a must have (must fetch now), then he is to be expedited.

Comment: The OP asked for "fetched later," which I took to be the opposite of deferred. A student who was waitlisted is not likely to be expedited later. However, I do like your "pending" list: being placed on pending status sounds closer to the thought of "fetched later."

Answer (score 0):

The question seeks a noun for "something which should be deferred", or "something which should be fetched later", and also seeks a word having opposite meaning.  I'll present pairs of words that are apposite and opposite, even if not always nouns.  Also, as other answerers have done, I'll mostly ignore the *should* of the question, and instead offer terms for something that *is* deferred.

• *[masses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/masses)* ("lower classes") and *[elite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elite)* ("choicest or most select of a group")
• *[sidetracked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidetrack)* or *[sidelined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sideline)*  and *[mainlined](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mainline)*
• *[waiters](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waiter)* and *[rushees](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rushee)*, used figuratively
• *NIP* (not-important person [possibly a neologism]) and *VIP* (very-important person)
• *[backlog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backlog)* ("accumulation or buildup, especially of unfilled orders or unfinished work") and *[expedited](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expedited)* ("accelerated; executed or dispatched quickly").

Summary: *backlog* may serve well for "something that is deferred", and *elite* for "something that is expedited". They are opposites of other terms mentioned; but not being apposite, are not opposites of each other.

Answer (score 0):

**Oppsite of something that should be "fetched later"...**

"of immediate importance" / "of immediate import"

"expediteable"

"urgent"

"critical"

"crucial"

"imperative"

"insistant"

"vital"

"pressing"

"exigent"

**Synonyms:**

"deferable"

"postponeable"

"delayable"

"of less importance" / "of less import"

"unexpeditable" (although this would mean Can't hasten rather than shouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

How about "Raincheck"? - not sure whether it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the title question, perhaps "continuance" or "contingency" would work.  Although the first word has a specific definition in legal practice, it can easily be extended to other matters as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there a noun for something which should be deferred?

   - You could just call it the deferred, but as far as a specific noun, not that I know of. I suppose you could call it a deferand, deferree, the deferred, etc. I think deferand sounds pretty good. Actually, if it's the title of a list, you could just say "things deferred", or more generic yet would be "stuff deferred".
2. What would be the opposite for something which should be "fetched later"?

   - That would be something that needs to be "gotten now", as a title "things to get now".

That said, when you can't find related words, find a synonym and start exploring those words. You will probably come up with something eventually.