# "Postpone", "delay" and "defer"

Tags: differences, verbs

I'm Russian and in the Russian language we use one word if we want to say that something will happen later than it has been planned. So usually I have difficulty in choosing a proper word among *postpone*, *delay* and *defer*.

I understand they bear slightly different tinges of meaning but hitherto I have failed to catch this difference.

Comment: Please, provide the Russian word. Some of us do speak Russian :)

Comment: Well, it's 'отложить'. There's also a word 'задержать' but it's the Russian rather for 'detain'.

Comment: Hm, also we use the word 'переносить' but in my opinion it can fully substitute 'откладывать'. :-)

Comment: Also see [#32069](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32069/fetched-later-deferred-and-gotten-now), “Fetched later/deferred and gotten now”, a sort of opposite question but might be helpful

Comment: Отсрочить, отнести, отодвинуть, приостановить, передвинуть, перенести, отложить в долгий ящик, отложить на потом, and probably a dozen more. Wevs. Russian is a red herring anyway. There is a difference between the three English verbs, and we can explain it in English, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @ЯegDwight I put those Russian words just on request. :-) And as to your example some of those words and collocations either have meaning which is not covered by those three words or can be translated in all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is considerable overlap, but there are distinctions.

**Postpone** is voluntary, an action initiated by someone who has the authority to delay an existing plan.  For example, "Jack decided to postpone the meeting until tomorrow.  The game was postponed due to rain."

You can use **delay** pretty much anywhere you use *postpone*, but *delay* doesn't carry the same voluntary connotation.  "I was delayed because of heavy traffic." Also, *delay* can be a noun. "The delay was unforeseeable."

**Defer** has a suggestion of being de-prioritized.  It is a much less common synonym for *postpone*.  It also implies that the action was initiated by someone who has the authority to delay an existing plan, except that the postponement occurred due to something beyond that person's control. For instance, you could possibly say "Jack decided to defer the meeting to a later date because the scribe was called up for jury duty."

While defer and postpone overlap, I think defer and delay do not so much.  In other words, you can use delay in all these examples, but defer only fits where postpone also works.

Comment: [Postponed for a rain delay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_delay)?

Comment: @Shog: A game could be delayed due to rain, but then possibly postponed if the rain didn't eventually yield to milder weather. Seems like you've pointed out another subtle difference: in some contexts _delay_ is more short-term, while _postpone_ is more long term. I'd say it like this, "After a 45-minute rain delay, the game was postponed until tomorrow."

Answer (score 4):

According to the comments, where you claim that you're looking for a proper substitution for отложить, you should definitely use *postpone.*

When you postpone something, you inform other people that a pre-planned event will happen at a later time/day than expected. Postpone isn't very negative word, as it's done in a timely manner.

However, delay/defer carry more negative connotations, as these actions aren't necessarily pre-planned and carefully executed. You **delay** a meeting by being late when stuck in traffic. That's negative. However, you can carefully **postpone** a meeting a few days in advance, if for example you're sick.

Comment: Well, I was not totally correct saying that Russians content themselves with only one word and these two answers have proven this. The Russian word 'задерживать' pretty well matches *delay* in terms of time relations, not only *detain*. As to two other words *postpone* and *defer* I think now I understand the difference. Thank you very much.

Comment: Defer does not neccessarily have a negative connotation. I'd say it's mostly neutral.

Answer (score 1):

What about delayed payment terms in buyer-supplier agreements?
What's the most common English word for a **deferred / delayed / postponed payment** that a manufacturer is obliged to pay to their supplier as soon as a certain time period passes after delivery? These payment terms are usually laid out in a supply contract, but I'm not sure which of the above listed words best suits this context.

Answer (score -1):

Based on popular usage, but worth checking statistically:

**to defer** usually includes the new date
"The meeting was deferred to next Tuesday
**to postpone** usually means that the new date will be set later
"Because of the weather, the game was postponed, we will inform you of the new date."

Comment: Hi, Buczko, and welcome to ELU. Citing references (even definitions) to support your position would make this a better answer. Otherwise this can be seen as just your opinion, and we try to give answers with some kind of authoritative reference here. Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.