# What is the scope of using shelved, postponed, adjourned, put off?

Tags: differences, verbs

- postponed
- shelved
- adjourned
- put off

Exactly as in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81414/postpone-delay-and-defer), I have a problem with choosing the scope of using those synonyms of *postponed*. What is the scope of using each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Postponed* suggests a temporary cancellation of an event, usually with a confirmed date in the future for reconvening.

> The meeting was postponed until next Tuesday.

*Adjourned* is used in almost exactly the same way, though it is usually used *during* an event rather than before.

> "This meeting is adjourned until tomorrow."

*Put off* is simply a more informal way of saying *postponed*

> Let's put off the meeting until next week

but it can also mean *deterred*

> I was put off by the high prices.

*Shelved* suggests a longer term cancellation, and usually refers to a project or piece of work rather than an event. It also usually does not convey a specified time period for renewal.

> The monorail project has been shelved for the time being.